# OnMarkerClick() Method not working Android Studio

Tags: java, api, android-studio, google-maps, kml

I have tried many of the solutions that abound here in the forum of the operation of onmarkerclick () but none have worked.

I am working with an app that uses the google maps api and we want to program a route tracer.

The operation that I am trying to achieve now is that by clicking on a marker you can trace the path to it, the problem is that the onmarkerclick method is not working or returning anything.

I will add the 2 parts of the code that I consider important to be able to find the solution to the problem:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        //  Add layer

        try {
            layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kmltest, getApplicationContext());
            layer.addLayerToMap();
            // Set a listener for geometry clicked events.
            layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new KmlLayer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                    Log.i("KML", "Feature clicked: " + feature.getProperty("CUA_DESCRI"));
                }
            });

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // end of layer add
    }


public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d("Comprobar markerclick", "onMarkerClick !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ");

        btnTrazarRuta.hide();

        //El destino que buscaremos al dar click 
        destinoRutaUnica = marker.getPosition().latitude + "," + marker.getPosition().longitude;


        return false;
    }
```

The onmarkerclick method should hide a button and get the position of the marker, but before that I put a logd to be able to see if it was at least entering the method, but no. It shows absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Once you add a KML layer, it will handle the clicks. You need to instruct the KML layer to delegate the clicks to e.g. your markers or polylines.

here's how to do it with markers (same principle for polylines etc):

```
MarkerManager markerManager = new MarkerManager(map);
MarkerManager.Collection markerCollection = markerManager.newCollection();
```

... where map is GoogleMap. 
Now when adding a marker to the map
instead of doing:

```
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);
```

do:

```
markerCollection.addMarker(markerOptions)
markerCollection.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener);
```

And now the final hint:

When adding a KML object to the map, pass in the markerManager (and polylineManager etc):

```
KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(map, R.raw.kmltest, ctxt, markerManager, polygonManager, polylineManager, groundOverlayManager, (cache));
```

In case you only use markers, it would simply be:

```
KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(map, R.raw.kmltest, ctxt, markerManager, null, null, null, null);
```

... and watch ALL your click listeners work

Answer (score 0):

Fron anyone who got the same problem.

in my case it was the line:

```
layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.kmltest, getApplicationContext());
```

apparently, onmarkerclick() and at the same time oninfowindowsclick() stop working when working with a KML layer.

I don't know exactly why.